# On select of combobox value, label has to be displayed dynamically after a select query from database

Tags: php, mysql

In a file following code is written which populate the value of combobox :

```
<select id="company" required="required" class="form-control" value = "select"    name="subject_code" placeholder="Select" >
   <?php
     //Iterating list of subjects available to be filled .
    echo "<option> Select </option>";
     foreach ($subjects_to_fill as $subject_id => $subject_name) {
          # code...                             
             echo "<option value=".$subject_id."> ".$subject_name." </option>";

      }                                              
     ?>
</select>
```

On selecting a particular item from the combobox, I **want to display the faculty_name dynamically from `faculty_table` on the basis of `$subject_id`**.

**table structure:**

```
faculty_table(faculty_id,faculty_name,subject_id)
subject_table(subject_id,subject_name,faculty_id)
```

Comment: You need to write a query (JOIN) to the database that you return this information.

Comment: Show us your tables structures.

Comment: I can write that query but after writing it the how to display the result on the same page without loading it

Comment: MySQL is you database?

Comment: Yes MySQL is the database.

Comment: Why dont you use ajax

Comment: @IndraKumarS The question has nothing to do with AJAX.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 See his comments.... He mentioned "without loading it".

Comment: The database structure is bad. There is an appeal of the Cross.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use ajax for this task.

Add a `<div>` and below script in your current file.

```
<div id="faculty"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function get_faculty()
       {
        var id = document.getElementById("company").value;
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_faculty.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(html)
            {
            $("#faculty").html(html);
            } 
        });
       }

</script>
```

Now create another get_faculty.php file in same folder which will be called on onchange event of company dropdown.

Write below code in that file

```
    if($_POST['id'])
     {
     $id=$_POST['id'];

     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pass","dbname");
     $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT faculty_name from faculty_table where subject_id = ".$id);
                   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                   {
                       echo $row['faculty_name'];

                   }
     }
```

Dont forget to write mysqli_connect credentials and query accordingly.

Comment: The database structure is bad. To solve this I would start from scratch. Rather than wade further into it and patch.

Comment: @rick_nilesh: Your implementation works for me thanx.